# Where to store an encryption key to be used throughout application (Ruby On Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to store an encryption key that is going to be accessed through the application globally. Is there a storage place for settings and configs? I tried searching but couldn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several ways to do something like this.

The simplest way to make something like that globally available to your app is to define a constant within `config/environment.rb` (or `config/environments/production.rb`.

However, with sensitive data it's important that they're decoupled from your primary SCM and only available within the production environment - at least this way, if your code is compromised, your encryption key is safe.

There's a couple of methods of doing this that I know of - one would be to set they key in an environment variable, which can then be accessed in Ruby through `ENV['variable_name]`.

Another option is to store it in an external file that's de-coupled from your code repository, then have that read in with an initializer.

Whichever way you do it, you can combine this approach with a constant declaration in `config/environment.rb`:

```
# config/environment.rb
ENCRYPTION_KEY = ENV['encryption_key']
```

This way, should you change the storage location of your key, you only need to change one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set all your secret constants in a config/initializers/01_secrets.rb file. Here are a few things to think about:

- The 01 prefix is to make sure that
  the secret constants are set before other
  initializers that make use of these
  constants are loaded.
- The 01_secrets.rb file should not be
  checked in to your SCM.
- The server(s) that store this file
  must be properly secured and the file
  itself should have maximum security.

E.g.

```
# config/initilizers/01_secret.rb
ENV['ENCRYPTION_KEY'] = "your_key"
```